# How to give readonly permission to postgres database role?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

Hi I have postgres database and I have created user like below

```
CREATE USER username WITH PASSWORD 'your_password';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE database_name TO username;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema_name TO username;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name TO username;
```

Now I am using this user to execute Stored procedures. I have executed below statement

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL PROCEDURES IN SCHEMA myschemaname TO myuser;
```

In my stored procedures I have select, insert, update  and delete statements.

whenever I execute Stored procedures and if stored procedure contains any insert,delete update statements its throwing error

```
42501: permission denied for table tablename
```

If i have only select inside the SP then no issues only problem with insert,update and delete. So my question is I have created user for the purpose of executing stored procedure only and i do not want to give update,delete and insert access to any table. So what should I do to execute inset,delete inside SP? Can someone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the procedures with `SECURITY DEFINER` which specifies that the function is to be executed with the privileges of the user that owns it.
[Check here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#:%7E:text=SECURITY%20DEFINER%20specifies%20that%20the,functions%20not%20only%20external%20ones.).
Make sure that the owner of the procedures have required privileges of all operations on resources within the proc body.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  procedure_name()
AS
$$
BEGIN
  -- UPDATE;
  -- DELETE;
  -- INSERT 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL SECURITY DEFINER;
```